# Python AND operator on two boolean lists - how?

Tags: python, list, boolean, operator-keyword

I have two boolean lists, e.g.,

```
x=[True,True,False,False]
y=[True,False,True,False]
```

I want to AND these lists together, with the expected output:

```
xy=[True,False,False,False]
```

I thought that expression `x and y` would work, but came to discover that it does not: in fact, `(x and y) != (y and x)`

Output of `x and y`: `[True,False,True,False]`

Output of `y and x`: `[True,True,False,False]`

Using list comprehension *does* have correct output. Whew!

```
xy = [x[i] and y[i] for i in range(len(x)]
```

Mind you I could not find any reference that told me the AND operator would work as I tried with x and y. But it's easy to try things in Python.
Can someone explain to me what is happening with `x and y`?

And here is a simple test program:

```
import random
random.seed()
n = 10
x = [random.random() > 0.5 for i in range(n)]
y = [random.random() > 0.5 for i in range(n)]
# Next two methods look sensible, but do not work
a = x and y
z = y and x
# Next: apparently only the list comprehension method is correct
xy = [x[i] and y[i] for i in range(n)]
print 'x        : %s'%str(x)
print 'y        : %s'%str(y)
print 'x and y  : %s'%str(a)
print 'y and x  : %s'%str(z)
print '[x and y]: %s'%str(xy)
```

Comment: x is a list, y is a list. `x and y` is true if and only if both lists are non-empty (an empty list is 'false-y', all non-empty lists are 'truth-y'): that is, `x and y` does *not* 'and each element' or otherwise care about the values.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

`and` simply returns either the first or the second operand, based on their truth value. If the first operand is considered false, it is returned, otherwise the other operand is returned.

Lists are considered *true* when *not empty*, so both lists are considered true. Their contents *don't play a role here*.

Because both lists are not empty, `x and y` simply returns the second list object; only if `x` was empty would it be returned instead:

```
>>> [True, False] and ['foo', 'bar']
['foo', 'bar']
>>> [] and ['foo', 'bar']
[]
```

See the [*Truth value testing* section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) in the Python documentation:

> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an `if` or `while` condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below. The following values are considered false:
>
> [...]
>
> - any empty sequence, for example, `''`, `()`, `[]`.
>
> [...]
>
> **All other values are considered true** — so objects of many types are always true.

(emphasis mine), and the [*Boolean operations* section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) right below that:

> `x and y`
>   if *x* is false, then *x*, else *y*
>
> This is a short-circuit operator, so it only evaluates the second argument if the first one is `True`.

You indeed need to test the values *contained* in the lists explicitly. You can do so with a list comprehension, as you discovered. You can rewrite it with the [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to pair up the values:

```
[a and b for a, b in zip(x, y)]
```

Comment: thanks for excellent explanation and esp. repeating the thing I had seen "if x is false, then x, else y", but not fully grokked. This is a case for RTFM and I should have read it very carefully!

Answer (score 24):

You could use numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x=np.array([True,True,False,False])
>>> y=np.array([True,False,True,False])
>>> x & y
array([ True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Numpy allows numerical and logical operations on arrays such as:

```
>>> z=np.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> z+1
array([2, 3, 4, 5])
```

You can perform bitwise and with the `&` operator.

Instead of a list comprehension, you can use numpy to generate the boolean array directly like so:

```
>>> np.random.random(10)>.5
array([ True,  True,  True, False, False,  True,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 16):

Here is a simple solution:

```
np.logical_and(x,y)
```

Answer (score 7):

`and` is not necessarily a Boolean operator; it returns one of its two arguments, regardless of their type. If the first argument is false-ish (`False`, numeric zero, or an empty string/container), it returns that argument. Otherwise, it returns the second argument.

In your case, both `x` and `y` are non-empty lists, so the first argument is always true-ish, meaning `x and y` returns `y` and `y and x` returns `x`.

Answer (score 4):

This should do what you want:

```
xy = [a and b for a, b in zip(x, y)]
```

The reason `x and y` returns `y` and `y and x` returns `x` is because boolean operators in python return the last value checked that determines the true-ness of the expression. Non-empty `list`'s evaluate to `True`, and since `and` requires both operands to evaluate `True`, the last operand checked is the second operand. Contrast with `x or y`, which would return `x` because it doesn't need to check `y` to determine the true-ness of the expression.

Answer (score 3):

To generalize on the zip approach, use `all` and `any` for any number of lists.

`all` for AND:

```
[all(i) for i in zip(a, b, c)]  # zip all lists
```

and `any` for OR:

```
[any(i) for i in zip(a, b, c)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
[a and b for a, b in zip(x, y)]
```

one could just use the possibility of numpy to multiply bool-values:

```
(np.array(x)*np.array(y))
>> array([ True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Or do I overlook a special case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `zip` function

```
x=[True,True,False,False]
y=[True,False,True,False]
z=[a and b for a,b in zip(x,y)]
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Martijn Pieters has answered, I would just add the following code to explain `and` and `or` operations in action.

`and` returns the first falsy value encountered else the last evaluated argument.

Similarly `or` returns the first truthy value encountered else the last evaluated argument.

```
nl1 = [3,3,3,3,0,0,0,0]
nl2 = [2,2,0,0,2,2,0,0]
nl3 = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]
and_list = [a and b and c for a,b,c in zip(nl1,nl2,nl3)]
or_list = [a or b or c for a,b,c in zip(nl1,nl2,nl3)]
```

Values are

**`and_list = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`**

**`or_list = [3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 0]`**

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer @Martijn Pieters and @Tony.
I dig into the timing of the various options we have to make the AND of two lists and I would like to share my results, because I found them interesting.

Despite liking a lot the pythonic way [a and b for a,b in zip(x,y) ], turns out really slow.
I compare with a integer product of arrays (1*(array of bool)) * (1*(array of bool)) and it turns out to be more than 10x faster

```
import time
import numpy as np
array_to_filter = np.linspace(1,1000000,1000000)                # 1 million of integers :-)
value_limit = 100
cycles = 100

# METHOD #1:  [a and b for a,b in zip(x,y) ]
t0=time.clock()
for jj in range(cycles):
    x = array_to_filter<np.max(array_to_filter)-value_limit   # filter the values > MAX-value_limit
    y = array_to_filter>value_limit                          # filter the values < value_limit
    z= [a and b for a,b in zip(x,y) ]                       # AND
    filtered = array_to_filter[z]
print('METHOD #1 = %.2f s' % ( (time.clock()-t0)))



# METHOD 1*(array of bool) AND  1*(array of bool)
t0=time.clock()
for jj in range(cycles):
    x = 1*(array_to_filter<np.max(array_to_filter)-value_limit)   # filter the values > MAX-value_limit
    y = 1*(array_to_filter>value_limit)                          # filter the values < value_limit
    z = x*y                                                     # AND
    z = z.astype(bool)                                          # convert back to array of bool
    filtered = array_to_filter[z]
print('METHOD #2 = %.2f s' % ( (time.clock()-t0)))
```

The results are

```
METHOD #1 = 15.36 s
METHOD #2 = 1.85 s
```

The speed is almost affected equally by the size of the array or by the number of cycles.
I hope I helped someone code to be faster. :-)