# Python3: [True, False] and [False, True] >> [False, True]

Tags: python-3.x

In python3

```
>>>  [True, False] and [False, True]
[False, True]
```

Why not [False, False]?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192163/python-and-operator-on-two-boolean-lists-how

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python AND operator on two boolean lists - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192163/python-and-operator-on-two-boolean-lists-how)